# Mostrar resultados de consulta con foráneas nulas

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días, estoy haciendo un gestor de una biblioteca particular con PHP y MySQL.

Las tablas de la base de datos, son las siguientes, algo simplificadas para no poner todos los campos.

**Libros**: nref, titulo, **autor**(referencia a otra tabla), **editorial**(referencia a otra tabla), **localizacion**(referencia a otra tabla), **lugarcompra**(referencia a otra tabla), **genero**(referencia a otra tabla), **subgenero**(referencia a otra tabla).

**Autores**: aid, anombre.

**Editoriales**: eid, enombre.

**Generos**:gid, gnombre.

**Localizaciones**:lid, lnombre.

**LugaresCompra**:lcid,lcnombre

El problema viene cuando quiero mostrar todos los libros almacenados, tantos los que tienen un valor almacenado en la clave foránea, como los que lo tienen en nulo, ya que así me lo han pedido. Quiero mostarlos todos en una tabla, mostrando el nombre del autor, por ejemplo, en vez de su id,relacionandolo mediante "**where libros.autor=autores.aid..**.".

La consulta y código que utilizo para mostrarlos es esta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from libros,editoriales,generos,autores,localizacion,lugarcompra where libros.editorial=editoriales.eid and libros.genero=generos.gid and libros.autor=autores.aid and libros.localizacion=localizacion.lid and libros.lugarcompra=lugarcompra.lcid";
    $resultado = $con->query($sql);
     while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "</td></a><td>".$fila["titulo"]."</td><td>".$fila["anombre"]."</td><td>".$fila["isbn"]."</td><td>".$fila["enombre"]."...........;
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

De esta forma, solo me devolverá los resultados que tengan todas los campos de la claves foráneas con algún valor.

He pensado en registrar en cada tabla a la que hago referencia, un valor que tenga su id a 0 por ejemeplo, y su nombre sea Ninguno, para así mostrarlo también, pero no sé si es la manera más óptima de resolver el problema.

Agradecería si alguien fuese tan amable de echarme una mano con la consulta que necesito o si debo atajar el problema mediante código PHP, para que me devuelva también las filas con alguno de esos valores en nulo. Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: No te sirve hacer la SQL pidiendo todo? `SELECT * FROM libros`

Comment: No me serviría ya que obtendría el id de los autores,por ejemplo, y quiero mostrar su nombre, que está almacenado en la tabla autores, de ahí la clave foránea.

Comment: Sustituye tu consulta con `or` en vez de `and` en el apartado `WHERE`. `libros.editorial=editoriales.eid OR libros.genero...`. Con que tenga 1 clave foránea te saldrá el registro.

Comment: De esa forma me duplica los resultados varias veces, asignando todos los autores,editoriales,etec... a cada libro y me sigue obviando aquellos resultados con valor nulo. También probé utilizando **libros.autor is null or libros.editorial is null...**, y ocurre lo mismo, solo que rellena los nulos con valores que no les pertenece.

Comment: Tal ves te sirva algo como esto `SELECT (SELECT nombreautor FROM autor WHERE idAutor=libros.IdAutor) AS nombre_autor,..` creo que podría funcionar

Comment: Relacionando en la condición WHERE únicamente el campo por el que quieres mostrar los resultados (en vez de relacionar todas y cada una de las tablas) me sale correcto. Te dejo un ejemplo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c29ba/1)

Comment: Pero en dicho código, no existe relación alguna entre la tabla Libros y la tabla Autores, por lo que no sería una base de datos sólida, ya que el id que introduces en libros, no hace alusión al id de autores.

Comment: Entonces en tu caso, cuando creas un `libro.autor` también se estará crenado un `autor.id`. Y en ese caso la relación en la sentencia `WHERE` debería funcionar.

Comment: No se crea dinamicamente un autor.id cuando registro un libro.autor. La tabla autores  se rellena en su propio formulario, lo mismo pasa con las demás tablas, para que cuando se registre un libro, poder seleccionar los id de autores,editorialres,etc.. a través de un <select>, donde muestro el nombre del autor, y envío el valor del id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de esta manera (Siempre con Left Join):

Primero, creas tu base de datos, por ejemplo:

[image: Estrutura de la base de datos]

Ahora, para obtener los registros de la base de datos ejecuta esta consulta:

```
SELECT libros.nref, libros.titulo, autores.anombre, editoriales.enombre, generos.gnombre, localizaciones.lnombre, lugarescompra.lcnombre from libros 
left JOIN autores on libros.autor = autores.aid
left JOIN editoriales on libros.editorial = editoriales.eid
left JOIN generos on libros.genero = generos.gid
left JOIN localizaciones on libros.localizacion = localizaciones.lid
left JOIN lugarescompra on libros.lugarcompra = lugarescompra.lcid
```

Como ya se han ingresado registros a la base de tados, al realizar esa consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Comment: Fantástico, mucho mejor que malgastar espacio en la base de datos para declarar un valor como "Vacío". Muchísimas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Bueno. Fue un gusto poder ayudarte.

Comment: Una última duda, se le podría añadir una condición **where**, y si es así, ¿en qué parte de la consulta?

Comment: Sí, por ejemplo, si deseas obtener los libros de un género en específico (suponiendo que se quiere obtener los libros de acción) podrías agregar lo siguiente después de la consulta: `where generos.gnombre = "Accion"`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de la sentencia **left join** al momento de hacer la consulta. Aquí hay un pequeño ejemplo: http://sql.11sql.com/sql-left-join.htm, aquí también hay una explicación mejor: https://donnierock.com/2014/03/04/diferencia-entre-inner-join-left-join-y-right-join-sql/

Comment: **left join** no me funciona ya que son varias tablas, pero he visto que se puede simular un **full join** en PHP, así que me ha servido bastante tu ayuda, gracias Daniel.

Comment: Publiqué otra respuesta detallando como lo podrías hacer utilizando **left join** Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.